# Clicking modal link does not show modal

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I have the following link on my page. When the user clicks on it, I want it to pop-up a form.

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
    <i class="icon-plus"></i></i>ADD TASK
</a>
```

This is the code for the modal that I want to show:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 style="color:red;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TasksController@store','method'=>'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
          <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('item','Create task')}} {{Form::text('item','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Insert here'])}}
          </div>
          {{Form::submit('submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>'submit','id'=>'submit'])}} {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Clicking the link does not cause the pop-up to appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo) in your link you need _data-target="#myModal"_

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `data-target="#myModal"` to your link (and you should be use `button` instead of `a`)

Comment: @girliosalama just add `data-target="#myModal"` to your link, like that `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal"> <i class="icon-plus"></i></i>ADD TASK</a>`

Comment: cant it be a link?

Comment: could you create a CodePen with your code and share it here or share your link code with data-target ?

Comment: i have just edited the same code above with what you've told me

Comment: have you copy/paste this code `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal"> <i class="icon-plus"></i></i>ADD TASK</a>`? In my side with your modal, it's working fine

Comment: @LoganBlangenois you add two close tag </i> :)

Comment: that's from the code of @girliosalama, and I can't edit it, sorry aha

Comment: its still not popping

Comment: @girliosalama have you added `bootstrap.js` to your project ?

Comment: <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: i have no errorrs when i click add task it just goes to /#myModal